# Odoo + Ripcord PHP XMLRPC library: "Could not access https://demo.odoo.com/start"

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8, xml-rpc, ripcord

I'm trying to make a connection from my PHP script to an Odoo server, but running into inconsistent connection problems.

I have 3 test locations:

1. Localhost
2. Domain A
3. Domain B

And 2 test scripts:

**Odoo Demo**:

```
require_once("ripcord.php");
$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();
print_r($info);
```

**Odoo Target Server**:

```
require_once("ripcord.php");
$common = ripcord::client("###.###.###.##:8069/xmlrpc/2/common");
print_r($common->version());
```

This gives me strange and inconsistent outcomes:

- Localhost + Odoo Demo: **success**
- Localhost + Odoo Target Server: **success**
- Domain A + Odoo Demo: **success**
- Domain A + Odoo Target Server: **Could not access ###.###.###.##:8069**
- Domain B + Odoo Demo: **Could not access https://demo.odoo.com/start**
- Domain B + Odoo Target Server: **Could not access ###.###.###.##:8069**

**Versions**:

Localhost:

- PHP version: **7.0.15**
- Ripcord version: **0.9**

Server (Domain A & Domain B):

- PHP version: **5.6.30**
- Ripcord version: **0.9**

What makes it stranger is that Domain A and Domain B are on the same server. What factors could determine whether or not the request succeeds? More importantly, how can I successfully access the Odoo Target Server from Domain A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was two-fold:

1. Domain B seemed to have a poblem with the default RipcurlTransport (Stream); perhaps a problem with file system permissions. Switching to Curl solved the problem of not being able to connect to the Odoo demo database.
2. The server is behind a Firewall, which needed to allow outgoing connections to port 8069. This solved the problem of not being able to connect to the production database.

Comment: RemiX, could you please give more details about how you resolved the problem ? When I var_dump records using search( ) method, then I always keep getting this array { "faultCode"=> 3, "faultString"=> "Access Denied" } . Also, when I call the ripcord::client($url)->start() method, I get Fatal error: Uncaught Ripcord_TransportException: Could not access

Comment: It's been 4 years since I worked on this, so I don't recall much of it. It seems I solved the problem on Domain B by switching to curl (don't ask me for the exact commands, I don't remember), and not using Ripcord at all. Did you try using curl instead? Did you also check the firewall for outgoing connections to port 8069?

Comment: So, instead of using the Odoo Demo, I decided to purchase some modules. And like you said, I opened the 8069 port for that specific IP address for the new database (like "Domain Z + Odoo Target Server"). And finally, it worked :) :) But I think the start( ) method is specific for Odoo Demos only, I mean the following code cannot work  :   ripcord::client('http://###.###.###.###:8069/start')->start();