# Cannot access to Odoo External API using PHP 7 XML-RPC - Access Denied, Fatal error Uncaught Ripcord_TransportException

Tags: php, odoo, fatal-error, xml-rpc, ripcord

I want to use **Odoo's External API** on my website, using PHP 7.

Like it is said in the [Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html), I've placed the [Ripcord library](https://github.com/poef/ripcord) in my httpdocs.
I have also activated the **XML RPC extension** on my server, **OpenSSL** was already activated, and the website is even **secured** (there's the lock icon in the address bar).

I want to test that with **Odoo Demo Trial** before we buy licenses. So in my PHP code, I have put the same `username/password` as the one I used to connect to [my Odoo demo account](https://lgb-test.odoo.com/web/login).

**1°)** But I get `faultCode` and `faultString` (Access Denied)

```
$url = 'https://lgb-test.odoo.com';  // Odoo Demo Trial
$db = 'lgb-test';
$username = 'johndoe@mywebsiteexample.com';  // Same Email as the one to connect to https://lgb-test.odoo.com/web/login
$password = 'mypasswordexample';  // Same Password as the one to connect to https://lgb-test.odoo.com/web/login

require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

$common = ripcord::client($url.'/xmlrpc/2/common');
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

echo('UID:');
var_dump($uid);
echo('<br/>');

$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");
$partners = $models->execute_kw(
    $db,
    $uid,
    $password,
    'res.partner',
    'search',
    array(
        array(
            array('is_company', '=', true)
        )
    )
);

echo('RESULT:<br/>');
foreach ($partners as $partner) {
    echo 'partner=['.$partner.']<br/>';
}
 
echo('VAR_DUMP:<br/>');
var_dump($partners);
```

Output :

```
UID:bool(false)
RESULT:
partner=[3]
partner=[Access Denied]
VAR_DUMP:
array(2) { ["faultCode"]=> int(3) ["faultString"]=> string(13) "Access Denied" }
```

**2°)** When the `start()` method is called, I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Ripcord_TransportException: Could not access`

```
require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');        
$info = ripcord::client('https://lgb-test.odoo.com/start/')->start();

echo 'hello';
```

Output :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Ripcord_TransportException: Could not access https://lgb-test.odoo.com/start/ in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php:488 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php(228): Ripcord_Transport_Stream->post('https://lgb-tes...', '<?xml version="...') #1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/index.php(10): Ripcord_Client->__call('start', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php on line 488
```

(Maybe similar posts out there, but somewhat hazy :

[How to use PHP7 Ripcord library to get Odoo data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440978/how-to-use-php7-ripcord-library-to-get-odoo-data/41445689?noredirect=1#comment116546686_41445689) .

[Odoo + Ripcord PHP XMLRPC library: "Could not access https://demo.odoo.com/start"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722189/odoo-ripcord-php-xmlrpc-library-could-not-access-https-demo-odoo-com-start)
)

So, I still don't know what the real problem is.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1°)** After a while searching for a solution, I finally decided to **purchase some modules**, instead of using the Odoo Demo account.

So, I just changed the credentials for my new database, and also **opened the 8069 port for that specific URL**. And it worked :)

Code :

---

```
$url = 'https://thedatabasename.odoo.com';  // Edited here. Opening the 8069 port was the last step to make it work :)
$db = 'thedatabasename';                // Edited here
$username = 'usernameofthataccount';    // Edited here
$password = 'passwordofthataccount';    // Edited here

require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

$common = ripcord::client($url.'/xmlrpc/2/common');
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

echo('UID:');
var_dump($uid);
echo('<br/>');

$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");
$partners = $models->execute_kw(
    $db,
    $uid,
    $password,
    'res.partner',
    'search',
    array(
        array(
            array('is_company', '=', true)
        )
    )
);

echo('RESULT:<br/>');
foreach ($partners as $partner) {
    echo 'partner=['.$partner.']<br/>';
}
 
echo('VAR_DUMP:<br/>');
var_dump($partners);
```

Output :

---

```
UID:int(2)
RESULT:
partner=[568]
partner=[570]
partner=[293]
partner=[378]
partner=[526]
VAR_DUMP:
array(193) { [0]=> int(568) [1]=> int(570) [2]=> int(293) [3]=> int(378) [4]=> int(526)}
```

**2°)** The **start( )** method **won't work** with the specific URL though

So, I'm not sure that the **start( )** method will work with something else than a Demo account.

Also, Odoo's support told me to not include the "**/start**" part of the URL in the script. But, with or without the "**/start**" part, it didn't work.

Code :

---

```
require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');
$info = ripcord::client('https://thedatabasename.odoo.com/start')->start(); // Even using the specific IP, this is ot working in my case

echo 'hello';
```

Output :

---

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Ripcord_TransportException: Could not access http://102.16.10.74:8069/start/ in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php:488 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php(228): Ripcord_Transport_Stream->post('http://102.16.1...', '<?xml version="...') #1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/index.php(11): Ripcord_Client->__call('start', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteexample.com/preprod.mywebsiteexample.com/ripcord/ripcord_client.php on line 488
```

**My Conclusion is :**

Odoo DEMO has NOT worked for me, even if I followed the instructions from here :

[Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html)

**EDIT :**

**1°) a/** We can get an IP Address (url is like "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") when we install manually our odoo server onto a different host server of our choice.

**1°) b/** But if the odoo server is installed onto Odoo's official website (url is like "https://thedatabasename.odoo.com"), we have **no IP Address**. And I managed to open the 8069 port **by asking for it to the web host support** of my website.

So, to make it simple, I edited "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" to "https://thedatabasename.odoo.com", for the case **1°) b/** :

```
$url = 'https://thedatabasename.odoo.com';
$db = 'thedatabasename';
```

Comment: How do you get the IP address to use? Also how did you open the 8069 port and use that port?

Comment: sjw0525, thanks for pointing that out. So, you can get an IP Address when you install your odoo server onto a different host server of your choice (with no domain name yet). But if the odoo server is installed onto Odoo's official website, you have no IP Address. Also, I managed to open the 8069 port by asking for it to the web host support of my website. Please see my edits.

Comment: I think you are doing a lot of the same functionality as us. Are you having luck with the API? We are not. We were able to get server type and Odoo version back from an API call, but not able to create an order via the API call

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were big data getting fetched. That's why odoo is returning access errors on `JSONRPC` and `XMLRPC`. So I used the limit keyword in executing the function.

> ['offset'=>1, 'limit'=>50]